# Generate Keypair in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am new to KMM, but trying to port a standard android app written in Java to KMM.
So, I have the following method:

```
private static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
    keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair pair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
    return pair;
}
```

With the keypair, I am going to sign a byte array and send the signature together with the public key to a java server, think of it as a variant of FIDO2.

Converting to Kotlin was not the problem, but then the java.security.* classes are used, which seems wrong when having in mind that there should also be an iOS variant. So my idea was to have in commonMain a function which would receive the byte array to be signed and returns an object containing the signature and the publickey for verification, in androidMain then the actual implementation for doing this with the code above - but how to do this for iosMain ? I can't figure out how to generate a keypair for signing using pure Kotlin for ios...

Comment: I'm not an iOS dev, but I think you could use [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/generating_new_cryptographic_keys) to understand how it's done on iOS, and then use the Kotlin bindings from the `foundation` package to use the same API but from Kotlin

Comment: Could you please point me to a sample or documentation where I can read more about how to use (and even find ;-) ) this foundation package ?

Comment: My bad, the correct name is `platform.Foundation.*`. It is part of the Kotlin/Native library when you use the iOS target, no need to add any dependency. If you use class names from the Apple documentation, you should be able to auto-complete/import these classes in your Kotlin/Native iOS sources (not in shared common sources). For example, here is a project of mine that uses iOS's native web socket implementation:
https://github.com/joffrey-bion/krossbow/blob/main/krossbow-websocket-builtin/src/darwinMain/kotlin/org/hildan/krossbow/websocket/darwin/DarwinWebSocketClient.kt

Comment: Thanks for your hints; I'll try with that. Besides... any idea why AndroidStudio marks platform.Foundation.* as unresolved references ? Will the IDE only find these packages when started on Macs ?

Comment: If you're not developing on MacOS, indeed you won't get the native macOS Kotlin bindings in the IDE by default. In order to solve this, you can use the [CompleteKotlin Gradle plugin](https://github.com/LouisCAD/CompleteKotlin) which fetches bindings for other platforms so the IDE can give you a proper experience. Not sure why this is not done out of the box, though